# Python (version 3.6.3) pandas (version 0.22.0 installed) import error

Tags: python, pandas, import

I get the following error when I try to import pandas in Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

Please, help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Follow the error advise.

Comment: where should i look for " setup.py"?

Comment: In the pandas source directory. You have installed it from source, have you not?